# How do you say 'tamale' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Google translate only gives 'tamale', which can't be correct, not ending in 'o'.

Comment: When Google Translate shows the same word/phrase as translation, it means it is not able to translate it.

Comment: Mi ne sciis tion. Multan dankon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Vikivortaro](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vortaro_angla-Esperanta_t): tamale (EN) = tamalo (EO).

According to *Granda Vortaro Hispana-Esperanta*:

> tamalo: speco de pasteĉo el viando, maiz-faruno kaj papriko